# Dynamically set the table name in a "has many" relation model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my database schema, I have multiple tables that hold generic data for objects, for instance I have a `user` table and a `user_data`, `post` table and `post_data`, and so. these `*_data` tables all hold a foreign key to the object and a pair of key-value. now in my laravel models I would like to have a single `data` models for these tables (rather than a model for every single one) and represent the `has_many` relation in a dynamic way where somehow I can define the table name according to the parent model. I think the parent model would have something like:

```
return $this->hasMany('data');
```

but I don't know how to express the inverse relation nor how to tell laravel which `*_data` table to use. so my question is, is it possible? and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Either create a model for each data_* table and use the relation as stated with `$this->hasMany('data');` and `$this->belongsTo('User');` in the data table and the user table.

Or you can use [Polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), I personally prefer the polymorphic relations solution, more neat.